# JS Scope return function

Tags: javascript

I'm walking through and implementing some new javascript feature in some code I'm new to.  I've learned quite a bit about variable scope within functions but understand this one.

In this sample, why is x undifined with the return function, but not the layoutInfo and TempXslLink attributes on the outer function showTempXslFoDialog?

Here's a graphic.
[image]

Comment: Hum.... I wouldn't think that x would be undefined.  I guess the callback could be getting executed in a particular scope. Weird

Comment: Ah, I think I read about this the other day actually, and I think the return function is reordered and actually defined before the var x is defined.  Just don't recall exactly what this was called.

Comment: Why is there a `.modal()` after the `$.Deferred` constructor?

Comment: Isim, turns out that is incorrect and the modal('show') is on the $dialog.